# How to add and remove CSS class names in Angular 2?

Tags: angular2-template

I get the data in the JSON format and must and I must to handle which item the user clicked on. I'm write this code and it correctly work.

My Example with DOM-usage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let person of personsList; let i = index">
    <span class="toggle-icon" (click)="toggleStatus(person.id)" id="{{person.id}}">{{person.name}}</span>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: ['.active { color: red; }']
})
export class App {
  toggleIsActive: boolean = false;
  personsList: any;

  constructor() {
    this.personsList = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Alex"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "John"
      }
    ]
  }

  toggleStatus(id){
    const span = document.getElementById(`${id}`);
    if (span.className.indexOf('active') >= 0) {
      span.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
      span.classList.add('active');
    }
  }
}
```

How I can add and remove CSS class names without DOM for a similar case?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just add "personIsActive" field, and use [Class binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let person of personsList; let i = index">
    <span class="toggle-icon" [class.active]="person.personIsActive" 
       (click)="toggleStatus(person.id)">{{person.name}}</span>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: ['.active { color: red; }']
})
export class App {
  toggleIsActive: boolean = false;
  personsList: any;

  constructor() {
    this.personsList = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Alex",
        "personIsActive": false
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "John",
        "personIsActive": false
      }
    ]
  }

  toggleStatus(id){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.personsList.length; i++) {
      if (this.personsList[i].id === id) {
        this.personsList[i].personIsActive= !this.personsList[i].personIsActive;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this no longer works in angular 8. class gets set but not unset despite it's condition testing and logging as false.